# Specified <entryPoint> is not valid. Check that the path to the entrypoint is well-formed and the entrypoint exists in the deployment

Tags: .net, windows, clickonce

I'm using clickonce deployment a applicaton, it works well.

The struct of building folder is :

[image]

There are everything under different  folders, named by version number.

[image]

Also the `Entry Point`(`.exe` file)
Generate `.manifest`file  and `.application` by mage.exe
Everythis is ok until now. I can install local, install online and update.

**The problem is when i change the struct of building folder**, i do it using 1.0.0.7
i create a new folder named "Release" under 1.0.0.7, move all files into "Release".(i can't post picture, so draw it )

```
 1.0.0.7
   |----- Release
      |----- .dll
      |----- .exe 
      |----- ...(everything)
   |----- HelloWorld.exe.manifest
```

create a `.manifest` using mage.exe, and update the `.application` .
In my mind , it should be work. every step was same as above (1.0.0.0/6). **Only add a `Release` folder**

**When i click `.application` to install it , i got an error **, both local install and install online, even i uninstall the old version before install it.

The error: Cannot continue. The aplication is improperly formatted. Contact he application vendor for assisitance.

The log content:

```
PLATFORM VERSION INFO
    Windows             : 6.1.7601.65536 (Win32NT)
    Common Language Runtime     : 4.0.30319.42000
    System.Deployment.dll       : 4.6.1590.0 built by: NETFXREL2
    clr.dll             : 4.6.1590.0 built by: NETFXREL2
    dfdll.dll           : 4.6.1590.0 built by: NETFXREL2
    dfshim.dll          : 4.0.41209.0 (Main.041209-0000)

SOURCES
    Deployment url          : file:///C:/job/clickOnce_pubish/HelloWorldLauncher.application

IDENTITIES
    Deployment Identity     : helloWorld.app, Version=1.0.0.7, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=d77022dd53fe7e1e, processorArchitecture=msil

APPLICATION SUMMARY
    * Installable application.

ERROR SUMMARY
    Below is a summary of the errors, details of these errors are listed later in the log.
    * Activation of C:\job\clickOnce_pubish\HelloWorldLauncher.application resulted in exception. Following failure messages were detected:
        + Exception reading manifest from file:///C:/job/clickOnce_pubish/1.0.0.7/HellowWorld.exe.manifest: the manifest may not be valid or the file could not be opened.
        + Application manifest is not semantically valid.
        + Specified <entryPoint> is not valid. Check that the path to the entrypoint is well-formed and the entrypoint exists in the deployment.

COMPONENT STORE TRANSACTION FAILURE SUMMARY
    No transaction error was detected.

WARNINGS
    There were no warnings during this operation.

OPERATION PROGRESS STATUS
    * [2017/9/19 18:52:36] : Activation of C:\job\clickOnce_pubish\HelloWorldLauncher.application has started.
    * [2017/9/19 18:52:36] : Processing of deployment manifest has successfully completed.
    * [2017/9/19 18:52:36] : Installation of the application has started.

ERROR DETAILS
    Following errors were detected during this operation.
    * [2017/9/19 18:52:36] System.Deployment.Application.InvalidDeploymentException (ManifestParse)
        - Exception reading manifest from file:///C:/job/clickOnce_pubish/1.0.0.7/HellowWorld.exe.manifest: the manifest may not be valid or the file could not be opened.
        - Source: System.Deployment
        - Stack trace:
            at System.Deployment.Application.ManifestReader.FromDocument(String localPath, ManifestType manifestType, Uri sourceUri)
            at System.Deployment.Application.DownloadManager.DownloadApplicationManifest(AssemblyManifest deploymentManifest, String targetDir, Uri deploymentUri, IDownloadNotification notification, DownloadOptions options, Uri& appSourceUri, String& appManifestPath)
            at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.DownloadApplication(SubscriptionState subState, ActivationDescription actDesc, Int64 transactionId, TempDirectory& downloadTemp)
            at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.InstallApplication(SubscriptionState& subState, ActivationDescription actDesc)
            at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.PerformDeploymentActivation(Uri activationUri, Boolean isShortcut, String textualSubId, String deploymentProviderUrlFromExtension, BrowserSettings browserSettings, String& errorPageUrl)
            at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.ActivateDeploymentWorker(Object state)
        --- Inner Exception ---
        System.Deployment.Application.InvalidDeploymentException (ManifestSemanticValidation)
        - Application manifest is not semantically valid.
        - Source: System.Deployment
        - Stack trace:
            at System.Deployment.Application.Manifest.AssemblyManifest.ValidateSemanticsForApplicationRole()
            at System.Deployment.Application.ManifestReader.FromDocument(String localPath, ManifestType manifestType, Uri sourceUri)
        --- Inner Exception ---
        System.Deployment.Application.InvalidDeploymentException (InvalidManifest)
        - Specified <entryPoint> is not valid. Check that the path to the entrypoint is well-formed and the entrypoint exists in the deployment.
        - Source: System.Deployment
        - Stack trace:
            at System.Deployment.Application.Manifest.AssemblyManifest.ValidateSemanticsForApplicationRole()

COMPONENT STORE TRANSACTION DETAILS
    No transaction information is available.
```

I compare the `.manifest` under 1.0.0.7 with other versions,  the only difference is a 'Release'

```
1.0.0.6 | 1.0.0.7
------- | ------- 
file="HelloWorld.Desktop.exe" |commandLine file="Release\HelloWorld.Desktop.exe"
codebase="HelloWorldModule.dll"|codebase="Release\HelloWorldModule.dll"|
...|Release\...
```

anyone could help me?  thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

I had this problem and it turned out to be mismatch of target architectures to AnyCPU

[image]

To fix this i had to add matching architecture when running Manifest Generation and Editing Tool

```
mage ... -Processor msil ...
```

[image]
Additional links:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/tools/mage-exe-manifest-generation-and-editing-tool

https://learn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/dotnet/framework/configure-apps/file-schema/runtime/assemblyidentity-element-for-runtime

Answer (score 0):

It is probably obsolete, but you have a simple mistype:

Exception reading manifest from file:///C:/job/clickOnce_pubish/1.0.0.7/*Hello**w**World.exe.manifest*: the manifest may not be valid or the file could not be opened.ed.

Check your scripts. It has redundant 'w' in the manifest name